# VBS Copying largest files first

Tags: file, sorting, vbscript

I've been banging my head in this morning trying to solve a task I can't believe no one has wanted to do before - that being to copy a directory of files & subdirs & all files over to another location but strictly copying the BIGGEST files first. Why? Because, from what I can see, this will help stop fragmenting big files being copied to USB flash memory due to the way it seems to copy the file then move it, leaving a gap the size of the file. Bigger files can't fit in that gap so make their own. ETc etc. End result - biggest first SHOULD hopefully mean 1 gap used for all copies and the resulting files all lined up contiguously after it.  I'm not anally retentive about fragmented files, it's to get contiguous files on a USB like isos/images.

So this is what I've got so far - 2 problems to fix :
 1 - only 1 level of directory is made on the destination path if it doesn't exist - I need it to make as many as necessary that don't exist yet
 2 - when the first copy starts it says "not enough space" even though there is like 30g left on this device to copy a 4g file.

All input welcome!

```
strPath = "C:\Data\Images\"
strDestPath = "E:\"
Set DataList = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
DataList.Fields.Append "strFilePath", 200, 255 ' adVarChar
DataList.Fields.Append "strFileName", 200, 255 ' adVarChar
DataList.Fields.Append "strFileSize", 3, 4 ' adDouble
DataList.Open

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

If Right(strPath, 1) = "\" Then strPath = Left(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)
If Right(strDestPath, 1) = "\" Then strDestPath = Left(strDestPath, Len(strDestPath) - 1)

'wscript.echo strPath & " " & strDestPath

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
 Call ListFile (objFile, objFolder)
Next

DoSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

DataList.Sort = "strFileSize DESC"
DataList.MoveFirst
Do Until DataList.EOF
 strFilePath = DataList.Fields.Item("strFilePath")
 strFile = DataList.Fields.Item("strFileName")
 strFileName = DataList.Fields.Item("strFileSize")
 strFileSizeLG = Len(strFileSize)
 intPadding = 15 - strFileSizeLG
 strDisplayName = strFile & Space(intPadding)

 'wscript.echo strFilePath & "\" & strFile & " == " & strDestPath & Replace(strFilePath,strPath,"") & "\" & strFile
 'wscript.echo strFilePath & "\" & strFile & "," & strDestPath & Replace(strFilePath,strPath,"") & "\"

 If Not(objFSO.FileExists(strDestPath & Replace(strFilePath,strPath,"") & "\" & strFile)) Then
  If Not(objFSO.FolderExists(strDestPath & Replace(strFilePath,strPath,"") & "\")) Then
   objFSO.CreateFolder strDestPath & Replace(strFilePath,strPath,"")
  End If
  wscript.echo strFilePath & "\" & strFile, strDestPath & Replace(strFilePath,strPath,"") & "\"
  objFSO.CopyFile strFilePath & "\" & strFile, strDestPath & Replace(strFilePath,strPath,"") & "\",True
 End If
 DataList.MoveNext
Loop

Sub DoSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles
            Call ListFile (objFile, objFolder)
        Next
        DoSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub

Sub ListFile (objFile, objFolder)
 DataList.AddNew
 DataList("strFilePath") = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFolder)
 DataList("strFileName") = objFile.Name
 DataList("strFileSize") = Int(objFile.Size/1000)
 If DataList("strFileSize") = 0 Then DataList("strFileSize") = 1
 DataList.Update
End Sub

Set DataList = Nothing : Set objFSO = Nothing : Set objFolder = Nothing
```

I've now worked using the code suggested below, and have this new script with a few error checks and fixes in.  However I still get the problem of unable to copy to USB.  I've changed the path to be the C drive and it works - so I can only assume it is because the biggest file is 4.6g and the USB is FAT32 with a theoretical limit of 4G files (windows copies to it fine though?)

```
Dim strRootPath, strDestPath
Const dictKey = 1
Const dictItem = 2
Dim tmp
Dim oFSO, oDict

'------------------- CHANGE PATHS --------------------------
strRootPath = "C:\Data\Images"
strDestPath = "C:\Copy" '"E:\"
'-----------------------------------------------------------

Main

Sub Main()
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If Right(strRootPath, 1) <> "\" Then strRootPath = strRootPath & "\"
    If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strRootPath) Then : wscript.echo "Missing Source : " & strRootPath : wscript.quit
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strDestPath) Then : wscript.echo "Missing Destination : " & strDestPath : wscript.quit
    ProcessFolder strRootPath
    CopyBiggestFirst
    Set oDict = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(sFDR)
    Dim oFDR, oFile
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).Files
        'Wscript.Echo oFile.Size & vbTab & oFile.Path
        tmp = Int(oFile.Size/1000)
        if tmp = 0 Then tmp = 1
        oDict.Add oFile.Path, tmp ' Key: FilePath, Value: Size
    Next
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        ProcessFolder (oFDR.Path)
    Next
End Sub

Sub CopyBiggestFirst()
    Dim oKeys, oItems, sFileSrc, sFileDst
    'Wscript.Echo vbCrLf & "CopyBiggestFirst()"
    SortDictionary oDict, dictItem
    oKeys = oDict.Keys
    oItems = oDict.Items
    For i = 0 To oDict.Count - 1
        'Wscript.Echo oKeys(i) & " | " & oItems(i)
        sFileSrc = oKeys(i)
        sFileDst = Replace(sFileSrc, strRootPath, strDestPath)
        CreateFolder oFSO.GetFile(sFileSrc).ParentFolder.Path
        oFSO.CopyFile sFileSrc, sFileDst
    Next
End Sub

Sub CreateFolder(sFDR)
    Dim sPath
    sPath = Replace(sFDR, strRootPath, strDestPath)
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sPath) Then
        CreateFolder (oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).ParentFolder.Path)
        oFSO.CreateFolder sPath
    End If
End Sub

Function GetFolder(sFile)
    GetFolder = oFSO.GetFile(sFile).ParentFolder.Path
End Function

Function SortDictionary(oDict, intSort)
    Dim strDict()
    Dim objKey
    Dim strKey, strItem
    Dim X, Y, Z
    Z = oDict.Count
    If Z > 1 Then
        ReDim strDict(Z, 2)
        X = 0
        For Each objKey In oDict
            strDict(X, dictKey) = CStr(objKey)
            'wscript.echo oDict(objKey)
            strDict(X, dictItem) = CLng(oDict(objKey))
            X = X + 1
        Next
        For X = 0 To (Z - 2)
            For Y = X To (Z - 1)
                If strDict(X, intSort) < strDict(Y, intSort) Then
                    strKey = strDict(X, dictKey)
                    strItem = strDict(X, dictItem)
                    strDict(X, dictKey) = strDict(Y, dictKey)
                    strDict(X, dictItem) = strDict(Y, dictItem)
                    strDict(Y, dictKey) = strKey
                    strDict(Y, dictItem) = strItem
                End If
            Next
        Next
        oDict.RemoveAll
        For X = 0 To (Z - 1)
            oDict.Add strDict(X, dictKey), strDict(X, dictItem)
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Const strRootPath = "C:\Data\Images\"
Const strDestPath = "E:\"
Const dictKey = 1
Const dictItem = 2

Dim oFSO, oDict

Main

Sub Main()
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ProcessFolder strRootPath
    CopyBiggestFirst
    Set oDict = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(sFDR)
    Dim oFDR, oFile
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).Files
        Wscript.Echo oFile.Size & vbTab & oFile.Path
        oDict.Add oFile.Path, oFile.Size ' Key: FilePath, Value: Size
    Next
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        ProcessFolder (oFDR.Path)
    Next
End Sub

Sub CopyBiggestFirst()
    Dim oKeys, oItems, sFileSrc, sFileDst
    Wscript.Echo vbCrLf & "CopyBiggestFirst()"
    SortDictionary oDict, dictItem
    oKeys = oDict.Keys
    oItems = oDict.Items
    For i = 0 To oDict.Count - 1
        Wscript.Echo oKeys(i) & " | " & oItems(i)
        sFileSrc = oKeys(i)
        sFileDst = Replace(sFileSrc, strRootPath, strDestPath)
        CreateFolder oFSO.GetFile(sFileSrc).ParentFolder.Path
        oFSO.CopyFile sFileSrc, sFileDst
    Next
End Sub

Sub CreateFolder(sFDR)
    Dim sPath
    sPath = Replace(sFDR, strRootPath, strDestPath)
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sPath) Then
        CreateFolder (oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).ParentFolder.Path)
        oFSO.CreateFolder sPath
    End If
End Sub

Function GetFolder(sFile)
    GetFolder = oFSO.GetFile(sFile).ParentFolder.Path
End Function

Function SortDictionary(oDict, intSort)
    Dim strDict()
    Dim objKey
    Dim strKey, strItem
    Dim X, Y, Z
    Z = oDict.Count
    If Z > 1 Then
        ReDim strDict(Z, 2)
        X = 0
        For Each objKey In oDict
            strDict(X, dictKey) = CStr(objKey)
            strDict(X, dictItem) = CLng(oDict(objKey))
            X = X + 1
        Next
        For X = 0 To (Z - 2)
            For Y = X To (Z - 1)
                If strDict(X, intSort) < strDict(Y, intSort) Then
                    strKey = strDict(X, dictKey)
                    strItem = strDict(X, dictItem)
                    strDict(X, dictKey) = strDict(Y, dictKey)
                    strDict(X, dictItem) = strDict(Y, dictItem)
                    strDict(Y, dictKey) = strKey
                    strDict(Y, dictItem) = strItem
                End If
            Next
        Next
        oDict.RemoveAll
        For X = 0 To (Z - 1)
            oDict.Add strDict(X, dictKey), strDict(X, dictItem)
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Patrick - interesting approach you've taken, looks good.
Just ran it and get error line 69 char 13 overflow: 'CLng'

Comment: Seems clang has a max value of 2147483647 which is 2g.  I'll try dividing the filesizes by 10 to shorter the number (and make at 0's into 1)

Comment: Ok so I've fixed the 2g file size limit here but now it's back to saying line 44 char 9 there is not enough space on the disk.  Even though there is 30g free and the biggest file is 4.5g or so.  Same problem as my original script  :/

Comment: Here's the changed code, though it still won't copy due to lack of space (which my original script said, which is rubbish, it has 30g free (tohugh it's fat32...windows will copy the files on np)
`Sub ProcessFolder(sFDR)
    Dim oFDR, oFile
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).Files
        'Wscript.Echo oFile.Size & vbTab & oFile.Path
  tmp = Int(oFile.Size/1000)
  if tmp = 0 Then tmp = 1
        oDict.Add oFile.Path, tmp ' Key: FilePath, Value: Size
    Next
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        ProcessFolder (oFDR.Path)
    Next
End Sub`

Comment: Added my latest code to OP.  Now it seems the only problem may be fat32 related :|

Comment: may use `CDbl()` (for Double data type) instead. Or change the file copy approach to use `robocopy.exe` to copy the files one by one? `robocopy.exe SrcDir DstDir Filename`

Answer (score 0):

OK!  I've now sorted the scripts in both flavours, and added some catches and informing messages - couldn't help myself  ;)
I also found I could resize my ghost images using ghost explorer to make them <4g so that now they copy to USB - yay!  The only downside to all of this is somehow some of the files still fragged but hey - these scripts still work perfectly as intended  :)  Take your pick!

```
Dim strRootPath, strDestPath
Const dictKey = 1
Const dictItem = 2
Dim tmp, totalSize
Dim oFSO, oDict

'------------------- CHANGE PATHS --------------------------
strRootPath = "C:\Data\Images\"
strDestPath = "E:\"
'-----------------------------------------------------------

Main

Sub Main()
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If Right(strRootPath, 1) <> "\" Then strRootPath = strRootPath & "\"
    If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strRootPath) Then : wscript.echo "Missing Source : " & strRootPath : wscript.quit
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strDestPath) Then : wscript.echo "Missing Destination : " & strDestPath : wscript.quit
    ProcessFolder strRootPath

    If totalSize = 0 Then : wscript.echo "No files to copy!" : wscript.quit
    totalSize = totalSize/1024
    If totalSize < 1 Then totalSize = 1
    wscript.echo FormatNumber(totalSize,2) & " Mb to copy - press OK then wait for 'Finished' message"

    CopyBiggestFirst
    Set oDict = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    wscript.echo "Finished!"
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(sFDR)
    Dim oFDR, oFile
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).Files
        'Wscript.Echo oFile.Size & vbTab & oFile.Path
        tmp = Int(oFile.Size/1024)
        if tmp < 1 Then tmp = 1
        oDict.Add oFile.Path, tmp ' Key: FilePath, Value: Size
        totalSize = totalSize + tmp
    Next
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        ProcessFolder (oFDR.Path)
    Next
End Sub

Sub CopyBiggestFirst()
    Dim oKeys, oItems, sFileSrc, sFileDst
    'Wscript.Echo vbCrLf & "CopyBiggestFirst()"
    SortDictionary oDict, dictItem
    oKeys = oDict.Keys
    oItems = oDict.Items
    For i = 0 To oDict.Count - 1
        'Wscript.Echo oKeys(i) & " | " & oItems(i)
        sFileSrc = oKeys(i)
        sFileDst = Replace(sFileSrc, strRootPath, strDestPath)
        CreateFolder oFSO.GetFile(sFileSrc).ParentFolder.Path
        oFSO.CopyFile sFileSrc, sFileDst
    Next
End Sub

Sub CreateFolder(sFDR)
    Dim sPath
    sPath = Replace(sFDR, strRootPath, strDestPath)
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sPath) Then
        CreateFolder (oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).ParentFolder.Path)
        oFSO.CreateFolder sPath
    End If
End Sub

Function GetFolder(sFile)
    GetFolder = oFSO.GetFile(sFile).ParentFolder.Path
End Function

Function SortDictionary(oDict, intSort)
    Dim strDict()
    Dim objKey
    Dim strKey, strItem
    Dim X, Y, Z
    Z = oDict.Count
    If Z > 1 Then
        ReDim strDict(Z, 2)
        X = 0
        For Each objKey In oDict
            strDict(X, dictKey) = CStr(objKey)
            'wscript.echo oDict(objKey)
            strDict(X, dictItem) = CLng(oDict(objKey))
            X = X + 1
        Next
        For X = 0 To (Z - 2)
            For Y = X To (Z - 1)
                If strDict(X, intSort) < strDict(Y, intSort) Then
                    strKey = strDict(X, dictKey)
                    strItem = strDict(X, dictItem)
                    strDict(X, dictKey) = strDict(Y, dictKey)
                    strDict(X, dictItem) = strDict(Y, dictItem)
                    strDict(Y, dictKey) = strKey
                    strDict(Y, dictItem) = strItem
                End If
            Next
        Next
        oDict.RemoveAll
        For X = 0 To (Z - 1)
            oDict.Add strDict(X, dictKey), strDict(X, dictItem)
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

and

```
Dim fso
Dim strRootSource, strRootDest
Dim rsFiles
dim totalSize
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'------------------- CHANGE PATHS --------------------------
strRootSource = "c:\data\images\"
strRootDest = "e:\"
'-----------------------------------------------------------

If Right(strRootSource, 1) <> "\" Then strRootSource = strRootSource & "\"
If Right(strRootDest, 1) <> "\" Then strRootDest = strRootDest & "\"
If Not fso.FolderExists(strRootSource) Then : wscript.echo "Missing Source : " & strRootSource : wscript.quit
If Not fso.FolderExists(strRootDest) Then : wscript.echo "Missing Destination : " & strRootDest : wscript.quit

CopyTree strRootSource
wscript.echo "Finished!"

Sub CopyTree(strSource) ', strDest)
    Set rsFiles = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsFiles.Fields.Append "Source", 200, 560 'double 255 byte limit ' 255 ' adVarChar
    rsFiles.Fields.Append "Destination", 200, 560 'double 255 byte limit '255 ' adVarChar
    rsFiles.Fields.Append "Size", 20 ' adBigInt      '3, 4 ' adDouble
    rsFiles.Open
    rsFiles.Sort = "Size DESC"

    Recurse strSource

    If totalSize = 0 Then : wscript.echo "No files to copy!" : wscript.quit
    totalSize = totalSize/1024000
    If totalSize < 1 Then totalSize = 1
    wscript.echo FormatNumber(totalSize,2) & " Mb to copy - press OK then wait for 'Finished' message"

    ' Source hierarchy scanned and duplicated to destination
    rsFiles.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsFiles.EOF
        fso.CopyFile rsFiles("Source"), rsFiles("Destination")
        rsFiles.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub


Function Recurse(strSource)

    Dim myitem, subfolder
    For Each myitem In fso.GetFolder(strSource).Files
        rsFiles.AddNew
        rsFiles("Source") = myitem.Path
        rsFiles("Destination") = Replace(myitem.Path, fso.GetFolder(strRootSource), fso.GetFolder(strRootDest))
        rsFiles("Size") = myitem.Size
        totalSize = totalSize + myitem.Size
        ' Build any necessary subfolder in destination as we walk down tree
        subfolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(rsFiles("Destination"))
        If Not fso.FolderExists(subfolder) Then fso.CreateFolder subfolder
    Next

    For Each myitem In fso.GetFolder(strSource).SubFolders
        Recurse myitem.Path
    Next

End Function
```